# `sfdx force:data:tree:import` FAILS when field API name has numbers in it

Tags: salesforcedx, bug, sobject-tree

I'm posting this issue again as it is not resolved yet. I don't understand why it's not part of the [known issues](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_index?tag=Salesforce%20DX) of Salesforce DX.

This has been reported [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G0000005OE3QAM) 5 months ago, with a temporary fix. The fix is unfortunately erased each time salesforce releases a new update of SFDX.

So, if you're wondering why `sfdx force:data:tree:import` triggers a **MALFORMED_ID** error, look at your field API name, including the namespace. It will fail if there is a number in the name. *Example: "Tax1__c" or "namespace1_Tax__c"*.

As described in the link, here is the fix. Open the file **dataImportApi.js** that can be found here:

- Mac Users: `.local/share/sfdx/client/node_modules/salesforce-alm/dist/lib/data/dataImportApi.js`
- Windows: `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\sfdx\client\node_modules\force-language-services\node_modules\salesforce-alm\dist\lib\data\dataImportApi.js`

You have to modify this regex expression:

`const jsonRefRegex = /[.]*["|'][A-Z_]*["|'][ ]*:[ ]*["|']@([A-Z0-9_]*)["|'][.]*/igm;`

to include the numbers expression:

`const jsonRefRegex = /[.]*["|'][0-9A-Z_]*["|'][ ]*:[ ]*["|']@([A-Z0-9_]*)["|'][.]*/igm;`

So, my question is more about how to make it part of the known issues so that it's part or their roadmap to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Still not resolved ... Everytime Salesforce update their sfdx package, my fix is gone. Please Salesforce do something, it's annoying !!!!